# While in landscape orientation pressing enter doesn't bring the cursor to a new line

Tags: android, android-edittext, screen-orientation

While in landscape orientation in my Android app, pressing enter doesn't bring the cursor to a new line, it simply looks like a space, but when it's switched back to portrait mode, the new line displays correctly. So although it's acting correctly, I want the user to be able to see the different lines of text while in Landscape mode. Can I get any advice? Maybe this is something it's supposed to do, but that doesn't seem right to me. Thanks!

My XML for this EditText:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/ingredientsText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minLines="5"
android:gravity="top"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Comment: can you provide full xml file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your view is overlapping with other view in landscape